# Add DateTime-Field with VBA in Slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I want to add a field via macro to my presentation/slide that automatically shows the current date.

```
 Shape shape = [Find a text shape to edit]
 shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some Text  | " + [Field showing Current date]
```

I don't want to insert a text that contains the current date:

```
 Shape shape = [Find a text shape to edit]
 shape.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "Some Text  | " + DateTime.Now
```

As I descriped the resulting textshape should contain some constant text + a field showing the current date.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will insert a time/date field into your text box:

```
Dim oSh As Shape
Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)

With oSh.TextFrame.TextRange
    .Text = "Some text | "
    .InsertDateTime ppDateTimeHmm, True
End With
```